# Difference between running immediately and delaying 0 millisecond

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I've a small example to compare:

```js
let div_onKeydown = function (e) {
  let $div = $(this);
  
  let code = e.which;
  
  if (code === 8) {

    console.log($div.text());

  }
};

$('[contenteditable=true]').on('keydown', div_onKeydown);
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

vs

```js
let div_onKeydown = function (e) {
  let $div = $(this);
  
  let code = e.which;
  
  if (code === 8) {
    
    setTimeout(() => console.log($div.text()));
    
  }
};

$('[contenteditable=true]').on('keydown', div_onKeydown);
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

The responsibility of the event: After I type some text into the div, press `backspace` key, it logs the current text to console.

Since I changed `console.log($div.text());` to `setTimeout(() => console.log($div.text()));`, the log had been changed.

[WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) mentions about `milliseconds`:

> The number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code. If
>   omitted, the value 0 is used.

So, my question is: why is delaying 0 millisecond different from running immediately in this case?

**UPDATE:** (based on @Seabizkit's comment)

```js
let div_onKeydown = function (e) {
  let $div = $(this);
  
  let code = e.which;
  
  if (code === 8) {
    console.log($div.text());
    
    setTimeout(console.log($div.text()));
  }
};

$('[contenteditable=true]').on('keydown', div_onKeydown);
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

It logs same result to the first case.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: I wanted to post, setting it before being deferred gives the exspected outcome `let div_onKeydown = function (e) {
  let $div = $(this);
  
  let code = e.which;
  
  if (code === 8) {
    var test = $div.text();
    
    console.log(test);
    setTimeout(() => console.log(test));
    
  }
};

$('[contenteditable=true]').on('keydown', div_onKeydown);`

Comment: @Seabizkit I just try, I gave same result to the first case :)

Comment: @TânNguyễn i don't think you followed me to well...please double check... `var test = $div.text();` capture the value before the deferring.